# How can I automatically fetch dependencies when installing a Debian package?

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, deb

If I download a Debian `.deb` package because it is not available through `apt`, I will usually try to install it using the command `sudo dpkg -i package.deb`. However `dpkg`, whilst being excellent at it's job, has one fatal flaw - it doesn't resolve dependencies. So if I have a package `foo-1.0.0.deb` which depends on packages `bar-0.1.0` and `baz-1.2.3`, then `bar` and `baz` will not be installed, meaning I then must run `sudo apt-get install bar baz` to make `foo` work.

How, using one command, can I install a Debian package file and resolve it's dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gdebi`](https://tracker.debian.org/gdebi) is the appropriate tool for this:

```
sudo gdebi foo_1.0.0.deb
```

will install `foo` from the given package file, and any necessary dependencies.